# Android/iOS app to facebook app

Tags: android, ios, facebook-app-center

I have the code for an application that runs on android as well as ios, how do I make this app into a facebook app? Note, it is not a web app, simply an application that is on the phone, I want to have this same app available on facebook. Thanks

Comment: Facebook App, you mean browser app?

Comment: Facebook apps (those running on the facebook web site) are developed using a different technology.  You'll need to completely rewrite your app for that.

Comment: No it is an application itself that is downloaded onto the phone.  I have the code for it that works for android and iOS.  I want to know how to "convert" this to a facebook app that can be used in facebook directly.

Comment: Thanks, is the only way to make a facebook app using a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, there is no "click to convert" button.

Android apps are written in java, ios in Objective-C.  And they may communicate with a server in the background for data persistance and such.

Web apps are often written using html+javascript for the client side (animations and such) and PHP (or another web back end) for data persistance.

Some things that will need to be changed:

- Usability/design (UX).  Apps use touches and swipes, that often do not translate well over to web.  So often that has to be adjusted.
- Size is another thing, apps can often be built to an exact pixel perfect size, that does not make sense on the web, since browsers are often much larger, and it can make sense to use the space.  Mobile apps are trapped in a small space, and scrolling and such is not simple to do, but on web, there is much larger space.
- Modality is often used in mobile apps (dialogs that appear and take over the whole user interface.)  This is not preferred on web, and should be converted also.
- Any kind of branding (outside of images, and even those) will need to be converted.  Text colors/styles need to be translated to CSS sheets for the web.  Fonts may not be usable on the web, you might have to check licensing, and may have to change them.
- If your app uses any hardware, like the camera or accelerometer, that is going to be an issue, since they do not exist on the web.

**In the end, it's a very large change**, and the app should be redesigned with web in mind so that it can take advantage of what is available.

Comment: thank you nycynik. If I have the code in c#, then will it work for facebook?

Comment: well, if that C# was for an asp.net service, then it could be used on the server side when building your html app.  But it wont replace the front end that you need to create.